# String Comparison with Multiple Words

Tags: java, string, if-statement, comparison

How do I compare a string with multiple words in an if/then statement? I tried this:

```
System.out.println("How would you describe your active lifestyle? Sedentary, Somewhat Active, or Active?");
        String lifestyle = sc.next();
        double activity;
        if(lifestyle.equalsIgnoreCase("sedentary"))
            {
                    activity = 0.2;
            }
        else if(lifestyle.equalsIgnoreCase("somewhat active"))
            {
                activity = 0.3;
            }
        else
            {
                activity = 0.5;
            }
```

But when you enter "somewhat active", it assigns the variable activity to 0.5. How can I get it to register that "somewhat active" is a thing?

Comment: Also you should be looking for Somewhat Active or Sedentary, instead of sedentary or somewhat active. (Cases) after changing it sc.nextLine().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `next()` method on the `Scanner` retrieves the next token, which by default is whitespace.  The `lifestyle` variable only contains `"somewhat"`.

Replace the call to `next()` with a call to `nextLine()`, which will get all words on the line.

Answer (score 1):

> But when you enter "somewhat active", it assigns the variable activity
>   to 0.5

Because in `"somewhat active"` `next()` will only retrieve `somewhat` as a token. `next()` method only reads up to the white space. As default delimiter is `space`. You can specify delimeter *i.e* `.` in your case and it will read token until the `.` occur in the input or better to use `nextLine` method.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
sc.useDelimiter("\\.");//provide input as somewhat active.
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `sc.next()` The `Scanner` class reads only "somewhat" i.e. (it reads only until the whitespace or blank).

Instead when you use `sc.nextLine()` The `Scanner` class will read the complete string as "somewhat active".

In general, if you want to read only one word use `next();` method. If you want to read a line (more than one word including blankspaces) use `nextLine();`